# What is the explanation for quran 6:101?

Tags: allah, verses

Asksalam wallaikum

> ˹He is˺ the Originator of the heavens and earth. How could He have children when **He has no consort**? He created all things and has ˹perfect˺ knowledge of everything.(6:101)

This verse says that Allah has no son because he has no consort. This verse is implying that Allah can not have a son because he does not have a partner. 
But Allah is omnipotent he can do everything .

> Commentary by Ibn kathir
>
> > How can He have children when He has no wife!
> > for the child is the offspring of two compatible
> > spouses. Allah does not have an equal, none of
> > His creatures are similar to Him, for He alone
> > created the entire creation.

---

**So the question comes if Allah is all powerful then why can't he have a son without a partner? . Because the verse indirectly say that he can not have a son because he does not have a partner**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ancient polytheistic religions believed that deities proliferated like humans, Greek or Babylonian tellings have dynasties of deities, and those deities even had intercourse with humans from where so-called half-gods arose. The Qur'an tells that none such has happened because God is One and Unique and not human. The passage has been revealed to remind us and our Christian brothers and sisters that any idea of God having intercourse leads us to a completely erroneous idea as to what God Is.
The assumption that, as Almighty, God can do what He wills  may be legitimate, but we can observe that obviously God does not do everything. God Himself does not act arbitrarily,  even if things happen against His will. Even less, He will not do anything that is neither His will and against His and our nature.
P.S. The Qur'an says that the Holy Spirit (Gabriel) enabled the virgin birth of Jesus (pbuh). This passage is to clearly point out that this does not mean that God had or could have had intercourse.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't mean that Allah isn't all powerdul, it means that how come that Allah could have a partner (which in this case, his partner would be like him), He who created everything, and that he is all-knowing, so how can he have a companion of his creation that suits him?  And he who is unparalleled, so can he have a son?  He is far above that.
If you read it in Arabic it will have a different meaning, as it's a problem with translation

Comment: when He has no consort this verse is indirectly say Allah can't have a son.

Answer (score -1):

The Quran when it comes to Mariam conceiving says it is easy for Allah to do this.  Every Christian would also be upset if you said Mariam had sex even with an angel before she conceived.  His ways are higher than our ways and his thoughts so much higher than our thoughts.  Yeshua is both priest and king. He is worthy of honor and praise and glory and dominion forever.  Amen.  Even Quran gives him that place with many more mentions by name than Muhammed.  He is the one closest to papa God.  He actually is the one at his right hand as the Word of God made manifest in the flesh.

Carismatic Muslim